# .htacces url rewrite exclude some directory

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

i have a problem with url rewrite, i have to exclude some directory in whitch there are some file as css,image and other. Howewer i have to

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !configurazione/ [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !funzioni/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !img/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !imgprodotti/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !imgslider/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !js/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !palma/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !sezioni/ 

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+).html$ index.php?pag=$1&prodotti=$2&prodotto=$3  [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/ index.php?pag=$1&prodotti=$2  [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/ index.php?pag=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you be more specific? It's not clear what the problem is or what you need help with from what you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteCond` is only applicable to very next `RewriteRule`. Try this code instead with `THE_REQUEST`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(funzioni|img|imgprodotti|js|palma|sezioni|configurazione)/ 
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+).html$ index.php?pag=$1&prodotti=$2&prodotto=$3  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/ index.php?pag=$1&prodotti=$2  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/ index.php?pag=$1 [L,QSA]
```